# Customise the android camera

Tags: android, camera

Can I customize the android camera which is to be called from the application in any way?
Customize means to add any text in the UI, make buttons with custom backgrounds etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own camera app.

You can download the Android source code, modify the AOSP camera app, build a ROM mod containing your revised AOSP camera app, and install that ROM mod on other devices.

You are welcome to modify any other camera app that is open source.

You are welcome to license the source code to another camera app from parties willing to sell you such a license, then modify and distribute that app, subject to the terms of that license.

Your app cannot attack other apps -- a camera app or otherwise -- to "add any text in the UI, make buttons with custom backgrounds etc.".

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own layout with a dedicated SurfaceView which will ouput the camera preview, with a button which will toggle recording on/off and with any extra UI you need.

I believe, CommonsWare, the author of the other, and much better, answer, has written a great book which, among, other things has a great example of controlling camera http://commonsware.com/Android/ there is a chapter on Camera

Comment: Now I know why Commonsware is so much expert in the subject of android camera. :)

Comment: Any clue which all controls can we access using a camera app we made using this way? I mean In my Sony Ericsson Tipo phone I have several other controls like zoom,video/photo. Some customization themes like beach and snow,night scene,sports etc.
So what all controls can we add to the phone,apart from of course the capture button?

Comment: Anything which can be accessed through the Camera public API. Zoom, video/photo settings, for example.